# How to calculate spectrum-weighted mean period using Fourier Transform?

Tags: fft

I am using EMD algorithm to extract the IMFs of a signal. Now, this signal may contain noise which lessens the significance of the IMFs. To calculate the spread function, the spectrum-weighted mean period has to be calculated using the Fourier spectrum as a function of the natural log of the period. My question is twofold.

1. Firstly, I am confused about the term Fourier spectrum. Is it Energy spectral density or Power spectral density?
2. Secondly how to estimate the integral using the formulation "Wu and Huang".
   http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/460/2046/1597.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I am new to this community. Thank you for letting me know this.